# How to match 2 lists with the same index position?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, indexing, match

Using c#
hi, i need to match 2 list, to asing 1 valor from 1 list, to the other list  at the same range.

is something like this :

```
public void SetText(TextMeshProUGUI texto )
{
    string mensaje;
    
        foreach (Collider2D x in collidersTextoEmergente)
    {
        nombreColider.Add(x.name);

        for (int i = 0; i < nombreColider.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; i < msgEmergentes.Count; i++)
                  mensaje = msgEmergentes[b];

            switch (nombreColider[i])
            {
                case "basura":
                    texto.text = mensaje;
                    break;
                case "DinnerTime":
                    texto.text = mensaje;
                    break;

                case "atomo":
                    texto.text = mensaje;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is a relly mess....
I want my function reconice the trigger or collider name and set the text automatically , the text that i already set in the msg list.
now i used this but is so manually....

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{

    SetText(collision);
}

public void SetText(Collider2D other)
{
    switch (other.name)
    {
        case "basura":
            cosita.text = msgEmergentes[0];
            break;
        case "DinnerTime":
            cosita.text = msgEmergentes[1];
            break;

        case "atomo":
            cosita.text = msgEmergentes[2];
            break;
        case "extintor":
            cosita.text = msgEmergentes[3];
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: To clarify your problem, please give us the output you are expecting and the output you are actually getting.

Comment: is already done , but thanks

Comment: If you figured it out, please answer your own question. Nothing annoys developers more than finding someone else who had a similar problem and solved it but never shared their solution. See [https://xkcd.com/979/](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: how i can share my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it you could achieve this in simplified ways using [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2)

**Option A**

Rather use e.g. a Dictionary like

```
private Dictionary<string, int> indexByName = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"basura", 0},
    {"DinnerTime", 1},
    {"atomo", 2},
    {"extintor", 3},
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    SetText(collision);
}

public void SetText(Collider2D other)
{
    if(indexByName.TryGetValue(other.name, out var index)
    {
        cosita.text = msgEmergentes[index];
    }
}
```

**Option B**

Why even take the route through an index? Simply directly use a dictionary like

```
private Dictionary<string, string> msgByName = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"basura", "Whatever basura message"},
    {"DinnerTime", "Hey, it's dinner time!"},
    {"atomo", "Whatever other message"},
    {"extintor", "Yet another message!"}
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    SetText(collision);
}

public void SetText(Collider2D other)
{
    if(msgByName.TryGetValue(other.name, out var msg)
    {
        cosita.text = msg;
    }
}
```

**Option C**

Now if you still want to be able to adjust these in the Unity Inspector to be more flexible you could do something like

```
[Serializable]
public class KeyMessagePair
{
    public string name;
    public string message;
}

// Adjust these in the Inspector
public KeyMessagePair[] pairSetup;

private Dictionary<string, string> msgByName;

private void Awake ()
{
    msgByName = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach(var pair in pairSetup)
    {
        msgByName.Add(pair.name, pair.message);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    SetText(collision);
}

public void SetText(Collider2D other)
{
    if(msgByName.TryGetValue(other.name, out var msg)
    {
        cosita.text = msg;
    }
}
```

Of course you could/should also add some mechanics to avoid duplicate names but I think that should do it for now ;)

Comment: this looks so good...never used dictionary so let me see how this works and i give a try

Comment: yep this works <3 thankkkkkks you so much :) and others that answer something !

Comment: @AgustinGimenezRojas just added a version you can still adjust via the Inspector instead of a hardcoded Dictionary ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to copy one list into another? If the second list is empty, you can do it like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < firstList.Count; i++)
{
    secondList[i] = firstList[i];
}
```

Remember that depending of the value inside the lists, this will make a shallow copy, no a deep one. More info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/).

Comment: this is just to assing the string valor in chatmsg[0] to the person in the other list at the same range. chatmsg[1] equals to person[1] etc. So , i only need to put a need string text

Comment: @AgustinGimenezRojas so?

Comment: i can do this using swith , and assign this string text to every " case " , but i look something automatic, just add 1 item( person ) to a list and the method knows his position and assing a string valor but maybe this is more complex to do assing the valor manually....

Comment: @AgustinGimenezRojas nono, forget about switch. Try to improve your question adding the code of items, persons, etc and I'll update my answer ^^

Comment: well in fact...I must admit, I am new to programming and using lists, so I am trying but I get nothing. but i'll going to update my answer take a look with my actual code that doesn't work :P

Comment: @Lotan couldn't you then just say `secondList = new List<T>(firstList);` ? ;) Probably even more secure since who knows if both lists have the same count

Comment: i must to try coz in fact i just want the position, index...not the context or value....

Comment: @derHugo you're (like always) 100% right. The only thing that I can say is that my premise was that the second list was empty, and since it's dynamic...but yes, your approach is better.